# Gvim syntax highlighting

Tags: perl, syntax, vim, highlighting

I was trying to make Gvim highlight syntax of a certain type of file(as Perl) using following command

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.bias setf perl
```

But as the first line of this file doesn't start with a #!/usr/bin/perl. Gvim is not performing syntax highlighting of Perl. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your .vimrc (I think Gvim still uses that)

```
autocmd BufRead *.bias set filetype=perl
```

If you just want to do it for a single file then try:

```
:set filetype=perl
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the line you already have in `~/.vim/ftdetect/bias.vim` and it should work. I have several custom files I've set up syntax highlighting for in this way and have had no problems.

(Note: if you're on windows, the path would be `~/vimfiles/ftdetect/bias.vim` )